# Python Multiprocessing utilizing another executable program

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, executable

I am trying to run an executable in a parallel manner. For that I am trying to use multiprocessing library. However, my code is supposed to run another executable file which needs an input file which is created by my code and outputs a results file which I need.

The computation inputs are gathered in an numpy array row wise, I would like to make asynchronous parallel run which will take different rows as inputs, feeds it to the executable program and reads the output file as results and gather them.

Doing the process, I noticed that one core is overwriting the other cores processes in the input file and I want to know if anything can be done to prevent that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You do not need multiprocessing to run multiple programs in parallel. You can use threads for that (cheaper and easier) or even just the process API with one thread in some cases. You should be aware of the GIL though.